# Blazor MAUI Hybrid App, what is the equivalent for builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress or reading from appsetting

Tags: blazor

In Blazor, Server or Client projects we could add something like this to have dynamic URLs.

How could I achieve something similar in Blazor MAUI Project.
what should in use in place of builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress ?
Is there concept of reading from appsettings in Blazor MAUI Hybrid App ?

```
builder.Services.AddRefitClient<IApplicationApi>(setting)
            .ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
            });

            builder.Services.AddScoped<ICountryDropDownDataService, CountryDropDownService>();
```